# How can I pause a function, and resume it without threads

Tags: python, interrupt

I am using a thread to calculate the delay time. For example, if I call 200ms delay, a sub-function runs, beside that, my thread gets the system's time and a while loop runs till enough 200ms, after, my sub-functions pauses, and continue running if delay called again.

Note: pause doesn't mean execute finished.

It is my idea, but I don't know how to pause and continue a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Python with a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), but your sub-function needs to cooperate.  It has to parcel the work into increments that block for less than your delay time, and it needs a `yield` statement.

Here's an example:

```
import time

def work():
    i = 0
    while i < 15:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.05)  # do actual work here
        yield i

running_func = work()
try:
    while True:
        start = time.time()
        while time.time() - start < 0.2:
            step = next(running_func)
            print("step", step)
        print("paused")
except StopIteration:
    print("done")
```